# add/generate layout xml using controller in Magento

Tags: xml, magento, layout, magento-1.7

I am creating a extension for the Magento 1.7.0.2 platform. I have been successful so far as the extension is used to basically load jquery & js which is managed in the admin panel.

The problem is there are multiple yes/no configurations (in the admin settings using storeConfig) and I wish not to load via .phtml using echo if, else etc..as these would not be available for merging/compression if requested via another compression extension (aka fooman of default magento) as they are static .phtml files.
(PS also would having a rather large, multiple echo if, echo else file be slower than xml?)

So I want to load these files via layout...but not using the .xml layout procedure under design/default/default/layout as there are too many config yes/no values and also model/select options which i cannot use in .xml structure (eg: ifconfig="value").

So I wish to load these files into the head block using the controller and do the echo if/else here so the appropriate configurations are loaded.

so far I have

```
public function indexAction(){

$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();


}
```

and I have been trying (just to start of from aka get working)

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->append(
$this->getLayout()
->createBlock('core/text', 'some-unique-name')
->setText('<script type="text/javascript" src="/foo/baz/bar.js"></script>')
);
```

I have read some snippets and suggestions from Alan Snow but have been unsuccessful as I wish to have the generated xml load on each page as well but maybe that is not possible using the controller

any comments, help & opinions are very welcome.

Comment: Got some great info from the crew at Inchoo with their post [link]http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programatically-create-magento-blocks-and-inject-them-into-layout/

Answer (score 1):

As one should use existing methods you should do the following:

`$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('javascriptfile.js');`